# Software for basic math notes at 5th to 10th grade level (10 to 15 years old)

Tags: soft-question, education, math-software, learning

So I've looked around, here and otherwise, but sadly can't seem to find quite what I'm looking for. I don't know if it even exists, I figured it was worth trying to ask, though.

I've found plenty of questions regarding softward to take math notes, but they seem directed at more advanced mathematics as well as users...

What I'm looking for is something a bit more simple to use, however. I'll explain.

A family member of mine has a condition, a problem that makes it very painful to write by hand. This makes it quite difficult to take notes, but she can make due on most subjects, with word and the like...the big issue is with math.
This is 7th to 10th grade math we're talking about, though, not college level, which is what most people seem to look for.

So I was wondering if anyone knew of software that would be appropriate for her? Something she could hopefully use to take notes and practice much like she would on paper.

Comment: Live-(La)TeXing is an option. It might take some time to adapt, but probably worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I am giving it a try here:
Go the the website

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180119075213/http://mathforum.org/social/math.disabled.html)

Maybe, just maybe you may find somehting (or somebody) to get some answers.
I gave +1 for your question though. But it is tough.
Arguably powerpoint slide shows is a method to have notes of how to do problems, is another thing that comes to mind.
Good luck